# Image change on currently hovered image based on class name - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a function with pure JavaScript to change an image source of currently hovered over image from a set of images with the same class. Nothing happens with the following code:

```
<section id="imgs">
    <div class="boundary">
        <img class="cage" src="cage.png" height="150px" />
    </div>
    <div class="boundary">
        <img class="cage" src="cage.png" height="150px" />
    </div>
    <div class="boundary">
        <img class="cage" src="cage.png" height="150px" />
    </div>
    <div class="boundary">
        <img class="cage" src="cage.png" height="150px" />
    </div>

</section>
```

And my JavaScript function:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cage");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].onMouseOver = function () {
            this.src = "cageF.png";
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to take care of `case sensitivity`, use `onmouseover` instead of `onMouseOver`

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cage");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].onmouseover = function () {
            this.src = "cageF.png";
        }
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xpcq39sq/)

Comment: Thanks, weird though. Not a JavaScript programmer so it's quite bizarre for me :D

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have answer to your question. Have a look on below links to understand JavaScript better.

[JavaScript case-sensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types)

> JavaScript is case-sensitive and uses the Unicode character set.

[JavaScript mouseover event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover)